# File renaming code is returning a single filename as '0'? Why?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet with two columns. In column A, I get file names from a specific folder. In the column B, I get new file names from different sheet using Vlook-up and few concatenations.

Using the below code in Column B, I was able to renames the file names in a selected folder. The code is working fine, except for renaming a single file as '0', which it is not supposed to do. FYI, the first file in the excel sheet column "A" which it supposed to rename is being RENAMED AS '0'.

```
Sub RenameFiles()
    Dim xDir As String
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xRow As Long
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        xDir = .SelectedItems(1)
        xFile = Dir(xDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
        Do Until xFile = ""
            xRow = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)
            If xRow > 0 Then
                Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
                xDir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
            End If
            xFile = Dir
        Loop
    End If
    End With

    Dim conState As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ObjWshNw As Object
    Dim strUsername As String
    Dim strComputerName As String

    Set conState = New Connection
    Set ObjWshNw = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    strUsername = ObjWshNw.UserDomain & "\" & ObjWshNw.UserName
    strComputerName = ObjWshNw.ComputerName

    dtEnd = Now()

    With conState
        .Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1"
        .ConnectionString = "server=xxxxxxx; Trusted_Connection=Yes"
        .Open
    End With

    'Inject the strSQL into the ADODB Connection and run it
    strSQL = _
            "insert into ggghhh.yyyyy.yyyy(ReportName,ReportStart,ReportEnd,Username,ComputerName,RuntimeSeconds) " & _
            "values ('" & strReportName & "','" & dtStart & "','" & dtEnd & "','" & strUsername & "','" & strComputerName & "'," & DateDiff("s", CDate(dtStart), CDate(dtEnd)) & ")"
    conState.Execute strSQL


    End Sub
```

Please let me know what need to be modified in the code to make sure that the single file name is not being renamed as '0'.

Comment: close your on Error Resume Next first with On Error GoTo 0 to see if any errors present then step through and watch the locals window and check variables are as expected (or use other debugging tools such as break on change of value with watches).

Comment: Is the first file actually present in the range you are trying to match against or is it retaining the initialised value of 0 for xrow and this is leading to the filename problem?

Comment: I didn't get your first comment completely. Answering to your second question, Yes the first file is present in the range. As you have pointed, initialized value of 0 for xrow can or may be the reason, but I am not sure about that. Let me know how I can the modify the code to avoid the filename being renamed as '0'

Comment: You should have On Error GoTo 0   before If xRow > 0

Comment: I am getting a "Run time error '58': File already exists" error after making the code change (On Error GoTo 0). In addition to that, the '0' file name still appears in the folder after running the updated code.

Comment: You are trying to rename a file to one that already exists? You would need a check that rename file doesn't already exist.

Comment: No I am not trying to rename a file to one that already exists. Instead I am trying to rename the XYZ.pdf  filename to ABC_1100_DDMMYY.pdf filename. In the folder, I am working on not all files are XYZ.pdf files but there are also few ABC_1100_DDMMYY.pdf files. So I am keeping the ABC_1100_DDMMYY.pdf files unchanged and working only with XYZ.pdf files by using the formulas.

Comment: Well the error message is telling you that you are so perhaps double check the value of the file name and file rename at the point the error occurs.